# asp:TextBox; is there an "OnFocus" or CSS equivalent

Tags: html, css, textbox, onfocus

What I would like to do is essentially:

```
/*psuedo css code*/
input:textbox:active
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Kind of like how there is `a:active` but do that for a textbox.  I know I can use Javascript for it, but for support reasons since I don't know who here knows JavaScript, I'm trying to keep it out.  Thanks.

I'd also want an inactive to take away the border.  Thanks.

Comment: This won't work in IE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your text box has id `TextBox`, you can use `#TextBox:focus { border: 1px solid blue; }`

Comment: Works in IE8 and FF3.6 for me.

Comment: If that's so, what is the "out of focus" equivalent.  Do you know?

Comment: the absence of focus, which is the default

Comment: The :focus pseudo-class is supported in all major browsers.

Note: Internet Explorer 8 (and higher) supports the :focus pseudo-class if a !DOCTYPE is specified.

Comment: Browser compatability of this technique: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/blurfocus.html

Comment: I'm not fully sure how to read that. lol. However, our biggest concern is IE as that is more than 95% of the browsers used to view the site, but even still, not a major requirement. Something I just thought I'd add in for bonus points with the boss. :)  I just tested it in Chrome and it works there.

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight the box with CSS, but it will not put focus on the box. To do that, you need to use JavaScript, whether or not you expose it to the developers. You can hide the fact there is JavaScript by using the techniques [here](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Focus-ASP.NET.aspx).

Comment: I don't think he is looking to put focus on the TextBox, but when the TextBox has focus to change the style.

Comment: That is correct anothershrubery.  You ever see those pages where as you fill out the form it highlights what box you're in, that's what I want.

Comment: @anothershrubery: If so, he needs to set up a style with focus.

Comment: Yeah, check my answer below, people are saying it's not cross browser but it seems to be from where I'm sitting. Although haven't tested Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

You already [have an answer for the general case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877417/asptextbox-is-there-an-onfocus-or-css-equivalent/4877466#4877466) on half decent browsers, in case anyone wants to get it working in older versions of IE as well then here is a hack I prepared earlier.  It's based on the [SuckerFish](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/) drop down menu code, the basis of this is that any styles you have for `:hover` you repeat for class `.sfhover` like this:

```
textarea:hover, input[type=text]:hover, input[type=password]:hover, textarea.sfhover, input.sfhover {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Then you have a function which attaches event handlers to `INPUT` and `TEXTAREA` elements for the `focus` and `blur` events:

```
function highlightInputs () {
    var sfEls = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        if (sfEls[i].type == 'text' | sfEls[i].type == 'password') {
            sfEls[i].onfocus=function() {
                this.className+=" sfhover";
            }
            sfEls[i].onblur=function() {
                this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
            }
        }
    }
    sfEls = document.getElementsByTagName("TEXTAREA");
    for (var i=0; i<sfEls.length; i++) {
        sfEls[i].onfocus=function() {
            this.className+=" sfhover";
        }
        sfEls[i].onblur=function() {
            this.className=this.className.replace(new RegExp(" sfhover\\b"), "");
        }
    }
}
```

The code only has to run in IE, so you don't have to worry about cross browser compatibility.  Then use some sort of IE detection method to run the function on page load only in IE:

```
if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", highlightInputs);
```

You could also use conditional comments or something like jQuery's `$.browser.msie` test if you have that library loaded already.